# Compare php array with sql results and do something

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array coming from a JSON file and a few rows from my database. Using [array-search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) I can check if values from my **$all_results** array are stored in my databases **match_id column**.

If values are found I get the key with my **$show_key** variable successfully. Now, I'd like to **do this** when keys are found and **do that** if none are found, but I have no idea how to do this!

I tried **is_int**, which does not work and ended in the **larger than 0** solution, which does exactly what I want if there wouldn't be a found value whose **key is 0**.

Help would be awesome. 
Thank you very much!

```
$json=file_get_contents('file.json');
$decode = json_decode($json,true);
$results = $decode['data'];

    foreach ($results as $key )
    {
        $all_results[]= $key['id'];
    }

        $pdo = new PDO('xxx');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM results";

        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) 

        {

            echo $show_key = array_search($row['match_id'], $all_matches).'<br/>';

            if (array_search($row['match_id'], $all_results) > 0 )
            {
                // do this
            }
            else
            {
                // do that
            }

        }
```

Comment: why don't you print a few key['id'] and the results from the db and compare it yourself and see that where there ids matching or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP: array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

Replace your condition-

```
if (array_search($row['match_id'], $all_results) > 0 )
```

with this-

```
if (array_search($row['match_id'], $all_results) !== FALSE )
```

This will return *the key* if the key has been found and false if it hasn't.

Also, this line is wrong-

```
echo $show_key = array_search($row['match_id'], $all_matches).'<br/>';
```

Replace it with this to see the keys-

```
echo $show_key = array_search($row['match_id'], $all_results).'<br/>';
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks! though I was going to edit it anyhow.

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped. Works.